# Java Sort object list based on value order (e.g. d, s, a, q, c)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have Events class arraylist where Events class is like

```
class Events {
Date eventDate;
String eventType;
}
```

Now I want to sort this array based on the newest eventDate first. If two or more events are on the same date then I have sort them in following event type order

`1. Maths
2. Science
3. History
4. Algebra`.

So if my list is

```
{ "01/01/2010  History", "01/01/2010 Algebra", "01/01/2010 Maths", "01/01/2010 Science"}
```

Then I want to sort it like

```
{ "01/01/2010  Maths", "01/01/2010 Science", "01/01/2010 History", "01/01/2010 Algebra"}
```

Please suggest how can I do this?

TIA,
Hanumant.

Comment: Homework? Why not tell us what you tried and failed?

Comment: I would suggest changing `String eventType;` to an `enum` since the sorting would then be easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but it should give you the idea:

```
class Events
implements Comparable
{
    Date eventDate;
    String eventType;

    int eventScore()
    {
        if (eventType.equals("Maths"))
            return 0;
        else if (eventType.equals("Science"))
            return 1;
        else if (eventType.equals("History"))
            return 2;
        else if (eventType.equals("Alegbra"))
            return 3;
        return 4;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o)
    {
        Events other = (Events)o;
        if (other.eventDate.before(this.eventDate))
            return -1;
        else if (other.eventDate.after(this.eventDate))
            return 1;
        return other.eventScore() < this.eventScore() ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: correct. But won't help OP if he just pastes your code instead of writing his own.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement you own [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) as shown [here](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-comparator-example.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your design leaves a little something to be desired. Try:

```
class Event implements Comparable {
    private Date date;
    private Event.Type type;

    enum Type {
        MATHS,     // MATH / MATHEMATICS?
        SCIENCE,
        HISTORY,
        ALGEBRA
    }

    public int compareTo(Event other) {
        int comparison = other.date.compareTo(date);
        if (0 == comparison) {
            comparison = type.compareTo(other.type);
        }
        return comparison;
    }
}
```

Then given a `Collection<Event> events` you can just `Collections.sort(events)`.

Answer (score 0):

As this sounds as HW you should implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface for the Events class.